# Find the best matching element from a bunch of questions

Tags: recommender-system, fuzzy

First, I am sorry I have poor knowledge of math and statistics (but willing to learn). So it could contain non-sense and I would be glad to precise my thought.

Here is the thing; I will have elements that will have ranks (let’s say it’s percentage) for all criteria. As input, I will have questions to determinate all ranks. These questions should not only have binary responses that will up some criteria linked to the question but also percentage of truth for some questions. Moreover, one question could up x criteria with different ratio.

If I consider that I will obtain a percentage of truth for all the criteria (even though, if you have advice to have a coherent scale of up for the questions it would be great :)), how can I find the best matching element?

As a start, I have found that fuzzy logic and recommender systems seems to be what I am searching for but I don’t know very well for a start what could be efficient and simple…

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is not very clear.  My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you improve it so it can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of thinking about this, but perhaps the simplest is to imagine that each "truth" feature is a separate dimension within a multi-dimensional feature space. This feature-space of say n-dimensions can be navigated by a vector (array) or n-elements. So if my feature space is [red,green,blue] I can express any object in terms of its combined red-green-blue vector. An object that is red would perhaps be located at [1,0,0] while a yellow object might exhibit red and green "features" and be located at [0.85, 0.70 ,0] for example.

Instead of an rgb colour model, if you're searching a teddybear database, you might have features like "cuddliness", "fluffy", "vintage", or "growling" - the semantics of what the features represent isn't important here, only that they can be expressed as a score between zero and one - and then combined into an ordered vector describing a position within the combined feature-space.

Then, assuming you can express a search condition in terms of a position somewhere within your vector space, it's simply a case of calculating the closest-distance from that search location to the next closest object in your database, for which you've pre-calculated and stored the feature-vectors. This you might use a basic Euclidean distance metric, cosign difference, or one from a number of alternative distance-calculating metrics.

There are plenty of pre-packaged code modules that will do much of the heavy lifting for you in this respect - it depends on what you're planning to use for your implementation, but I think it's more important to get an idea of a possible methodology, and in this case, the vector-space idea might be a reasonable fit for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it helps a lot! :)

Could my vector space have the dimension of the number of my "base features" which could not be expressed by a combination of other features?

Could each answer of a question represent a vector in my vector space, and, then, the sum of the answer vectors is the vector that I will compare to all my feature vectors through Euclidean distance?

Comment: Yes, so just to agree terms here, a dimension is equivalent to a feature. The objects have scores for each of these features (some being zero) and the searches are expressed as a collection of feature "scores'. These scores are each vectors pointing to specific locations within the wider possibility space. This space is only sparsely populated by points, each characteristic of either a specific "search" or "object" - the trick to performing a "fuzzy" search is to identify the smallest geometric distance between one and the other.

There are nuances here, but that's the essence of it.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! :) Is there any way to avoid full scan of all my feature-vectors when I will calculate which feature has the smallest distance to the search vector? The best thing would be to reduce the calculations to a sample of potential candidates.

Comment: It seems that I am searching something like that :). http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-onlogn-implementation/